# Oracle Sql - Time based sql injection

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection

When trying to do an SQL injection on an Oracle SQL database I have the problem that most of the examples in the tutorials do not work. I already found out that I only can use `CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE c END` instead of normal if statements.

The question I have now is how do I get time delay into the injection? Benchmark() and sleep() do not work either.

I already now that the table is named "flag" and the field name I want to read out is named "password".

My only information i get from the database is the time it needed to execute my input (or query since I bypass the input to inject SQL)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more details.

Comment: There is no equivalent of `sleep()` in running SQL queries. What you **can** do is to have the injection happen only if the query itself is started after a certain date and time - for example, if someone runs the query after June 1, 2020, at 8:00 am Europe/London time. But you can't have a query run TODAY, and never again, that will trigger the injection at a later date. (Unless your injection is able to schedule some other "job" or task for later - not even sure if that can be done, even if the target system is so poorly designed as to allow it.)

Answer (score 1):

I found the following SQL statement on the web at [SQL Injection Tutorial](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/cheat-sheet)

```
select dbms_pipe.receive_message(('a'),10) from dual;
```

I am not certain I should be participating in this sort of thing, but since I found it with my first Google Search, I will go ahead and post it.

I tested it and it delayed the result by 10 seconds.